# add variable to require in ImageBackground

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, imagebackground

I am using ImageBackground from react-native lib. ImageBackground using source={require('asd.png')} for example.

But I am trying to add variable inside to require.

```
const [image,setImage] = useState('./asd.png')

.then(image => {
            setImage(image.path) // gives 'something.png'
          });

<ImageBackground source={require(image)></ImageBackground>
```

But I am getting error. Invalid call at line 122: require(image)

Comment: Is your image a `network image` ??

Answer (score 0):

```
// Declare a varible here...
const img = require('./asd.png')  

// Example of a network image
const networkImage = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/799443/pexels-photo-799443.jpeg"  

const [image, setImage] = useState(img) // Use it here like this

// Static Image Usage
<ImageBackground 
    source={image} 
    style={{ flex: 1, resizeMode: 'cover', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
</ImageBackground> 

// Network Image Usage
<ImageBackground 
    source={{uri : networkImage}} 
    style={{ flex: 1, resizeMode: 'cover', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
</ImageBackground>
```

This is the proper way to use `ImageBackground`

Check this [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/image-background-test) to see working example

Also, have a look at the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images) for more help.

As the Docs says,

```
// GOOD (this is also correct)
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />;

// BAD (this is wrong...)
var icon = this.props.active
  ? 'my-icon-active'
  : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />;

// GOOD (this is correct)
var icon = this.props.active
  ? require('./my-icon-active.png')
  : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />;
```

Comment: But I need to change only './asd.png' name

Comment: For that what you should do is....create a variable `const img = require('./something.png')`.....then for changing it...Do like this....... `setImage(img)`

Comment: I really didnt get it. what should I write in useState then?

Comment: Edited the answer..Check again

Comment: ok mate I but when I onPress and select a new path. I am just sending path to the setImage('something.png')

Comment: I am not changing the path in require in your code.I edited the code to give some info

Comment: No...for changing image you have to do this...`setImage(require('something.png'))`...Check the snack again...I've implemented changing image in my snack link

Comment: When it becomes something.png =>  to anotherting.png. How can I change it. because I cant also make it like this.require(""+ variable).

Comment: In your example it is still static. I am getting value like 'something.png' I need to change it. Inside the require

Comment: I don't think you can change the images the way you want...It can only be done when the images are `remote` ..a `url` or something..but not with static images.

Comment: I get what you are trying to do but its not possible with static images..

Comment: then how people use add dynamic variable inside ImageBackground with url.

Comment: That's what I am saying....You can change it dynamically when `image` is a `uri`...something like `https://www.example.com/image.png` ..Then your way is correct..but when you want to use an image which is inside you project folder (as in your case)..then its not possible dynamically.. Check my points at the end of my answer